Will vue v-for auto generated links serve as backlinks?
Hi I am wondering if I create a v- for loop using a databases data that users have uploaded like this below.
   <div v-for =" example in example" :key="example.id" >
     <p class="text-xl">{{ example.name }}</p>
     <a :href= "example.hreftosite">
     </div>

Will the links be viewed as backlinks or will they not be seen as backlinks to the sites?
